# Change font size by using size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, adaptive-ui

I am using `size classes` in my `storyboard` to create adaptive layout and I have `attributed UILabel`s in it. Now I want to change the font size for iPad of these labels but it seems that `size classes` for `UILabel` with attributed text is not available in `IB`. So the question is how to change the font size of a `UILabel` with attributed string.

Comment: check this....https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangingtheFontforaSizeClass.html

Comment: I saw it....but the separate size class to change font is available for a label only if it is in plain mode and not attributed.

Comment: did you want different font size or different font family for sizeClasses?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Wes said:-

You should take a look at [AliSoftware's OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel). It is a subclass of UILabel that draws an NSAttributedString and also provides convenience methods for setting the attributes of an NSAttributedString from UIKit classes.

From the sample provided in the repo:

```
#import "NSAttributedString+Attributes.h"
#import "OHAttributedLabel.h"

/**(1)** Build the NSAttributedString *******/
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"Hello World!"];
// for those calls we don't specify a range so it affects the whole string
[attrStr setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
// now we only change the color of "Hello"
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];


/**(2)** Affect the NSAttributedString to the OHAttributedLabel *******/
myAttributedLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
// Use the "Justified" alignment
myAttributedLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentJustify;
// "Hello World!" will be displayed in the label, justified, "Hello" in red and " World!" in gray.
```

**Note:** In iOS 6+ you can render attributed strings using the [attributedText](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText) property of UILabel.

please check this question for better understand:-

[Iphone/Ipad Nsattributed string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring)

**EDIT**

You should also check this link to change the size of font.
You should modify it according to your requirement. like if you don't need dynamicaly then dont use method.`bumpFontSize` etc.

[Change the font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450669/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-a-nsattributedsstring-in-ios)

Comment: I have set my label as attributed instead of plain and now I want to change its font size....I am not doing any thing to this label with the code.

Comment: can you upload your attributed label's code portion?

Comment: As I said earlier I haven't done anything in code related to the label....I am setting the text property of UILabel as attributed instead of plain(default) in storyboard.